# Reducing size of C program to fit in qr code

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, compiler-errors, linker

I wanted to fit minesweeper into a qr code, which has a maximum size allowance of 3KB. As it stands, my program's binary is 12KB, and its object file is 3KB. I tried using UPX on the binary and managed to get it down to 6KB. I've been compiling with these commands:
`gcc.exe -Wall -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -c C:\Users\mlfre\OneDrive\Desktop\Minesweeper2\main.c -o obj\Release\main.o` and `gcc.exe  -o bin\Release\Minesweeper2.exe obj\Release\main.o  -s -Wl,--gc-sections  -lKernel32 -lgcc -lmsvcrt`.

I have not attempted removing the default libs because whenever I do I get a lot of undefined reference errors, and have tried many ways but each 'solution' brings up even more problems. I haven't tried editing the PE headers because they seem very complex and I have not found a low-enough level explanation on how to do so. Although I did make sure to limit the header files I used to just `windows.h`. I know the libraries I need are `kernel32` because most need to have that, `mscvrt` since its windows.h's library, and `gcc` because if I were to use -nodefaultlibs it would get removed.

My code can be seen here:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define WIDTH 100
#define HEIGHT 100
#define BOMBS 800

struct xorshift_state {
  int a;
};

int xorshift(struct xorshift_state *state)
{
    int x = state->a;
    x ^= x << 13;
    x ^= x >> 17;
    x ^= x << 5;
    return state->a = x;
}

void ExpandGrid(int fullGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT], int knownGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT], int blankPos[2])
{
    int neighbors[8][2] = {{0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1},
                          {0,-1},        {-1,0},
                          {-1,-1},{-1,1},{1,-1}};
    int curTile[2];

    knownGrid[blankPos[0]][blankPos[1]] = 1;
    if(fullGrid[blankPos[0]][blankPos[1]] != 0) return;

    for(int blck = 0; blck < 8; ++blck)
    {
        curTile[0] = blankPos[0]+neighbors[blck][0];
        curTile[1] = blankPos[1]+neighbors[blck][1];
        if(curTile[0] > WIDTH-1 || curTile[1] > HEIGHT-1 || curTile[0] < 0 || curTile[1] < 0) continue;

        if(fullGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] == 0 && knownGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] == 0)
        {
            knownGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] = 1;
            ExpandGrid(fullGrid, knownGrid, curTile);
        }
        else if(fullGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] > 0) knownGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] = 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    COORD characterBufferSize = { WIDTH, HEIGHT };
    COORD characterPosition = { 0, 0 };
    SMALL_RECT consoleWriteArea = { 0, 0, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1 };
    CHAR_INFO consoleBuffer[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

    HANDLE wHnd = GetStdHandle(-11);
    HANDLE rHnd = GetStdHandle(-10);

    DWORD numEventsRead = 0;
    DWORD numEvents = 0;
    INPUT_RECORD *eventBuffer = {0};
    int wait = 45;

    int startGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = { 0 };
    int knownGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = { 0 };
    int arrowPos[2] = {0, 0};
    int bomb[2] = {0};
    struct xorshift_state seed = {argc == 2 ? (int) argv[1] : 1};

    for (int i = 0; i < BOMBS; i++)
    {
        while (startGrid[bomb[0]][bomb[1]] < -1 || bomb[0] <= 0 || bomb[1] <= 0 || bomb[0] >= WIDTH-1 || bomb[1] >= HEIGHT-1)
        {
            bomb[0] = (xorshift(&seed) % WIDTH-1) + 1;
            bomb[1] = (xorshift(&seed) % HEIGHT-1) + 1;
        }

        startGrid[bomb[0]][bomb[1]] = -9;

        startGrid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1]]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0]][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0]][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        startGrid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1]]++;
    }


    while(1)
    {
        if (arrowPos[0] > WIDTH-1) arrowPos[0] = WIDTH-1;
        if (arrowPos[0] < 0) arrowPos[0] = 0;
        if (arrowPos[1] > HEIGHT-1) arrowPos[1] = HEIGHT-1;
        if (arrowPos[1] < 0) arrowPos[1] = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
            {

                if (knownGrid[x][y] == 1)
                {
                    if (startGrid[x][y] > 0)
                    {
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Char.AsciiChar = '0' + startGrid[x][y];
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = 10;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Char.AsciiChar = 'o';
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = startGrid[x][y] < 0 ? 4 : 17;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    consoleBuffer[x][y].Char.AsciiChar = 00;
                    consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = 0;
                }

                if(arrowPos[0] == x && arrowPos[1] == y)
                {
                    consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = 112;
                }
            }
        }

        WriteConsoleOutput(wHnd, *consoleBuffer, characterBufferSize, characterPosition, &consoleWriteArea);

        numEvents = 0;
        numEventsRead = 0;
        GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(rHnd, &numEvents);

        if (numEvents)
        {
            eventBuffer = malloc(sizeof(INPUT_RECORD) * numEvents);
            ReadConsoleInput(rHnd, eventBuffer, numEvents, &numEventsRead);
        }

        if(numEventsRead && wait <= 0)
        {
            wait = 45;
            switch (eventBuffer[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
            {
                case 38:
                    arrowPos[0]--;
                    break;
                case 40:
                    arrowPos[0]++;
                    break;
                case 37:
                    arrowPos[1]--;
                    break;
                case 39:
                    arrowPos[1]++;
                    break;
                case 13:
                    ExpandGrid(startGrid, knownGrid, arrowPos);
                    break;
            }
        }

        wait--;
    }
}
```

And if I turn on `-nodefaultlibs` this is the string of errors i get:

```
-------------- Build: Release in Minesweeper2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

gcc.exe -Wall -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -c C:\Users\mlfre\OneDrive\Desktop\Minesweeper2\main.c -o obj\Release\main.o
gcc.exe  -o bin\Release\Minesweeper2.exe obj\Release\main.o  -s -Wl,--gc-sections -nodefaultlibs  -lKernel32 -lgcc -lmsvcrt
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x13c): undefined reference to `fesetenv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `__dyn_tls_init_callback'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x1d9): undefined reference to `__cpu_features_init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x1de): undefined reference to `_CRT_fenv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x1e6): undefined reference to `fesetenv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x1eb): undefined reference to `_setargv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x1f0): undefined reference to `_CRT_fmode'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x206): undefined reference to `_pei386_runtime_relocator'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x25d): undefined reference to `_CRT_fmode'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x271): undefined reference to `_CRT_fmode'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2a4): undefined reference to `_CRT_glob'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
12 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

So now I'm wondering either a) how could i fix this nodefaultlibs error, or b) is there anything else i can do that i might've overlooked to reduce the size of the program ?

Comment: You might like to read [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)

Comment: Not that big improvement but: https://sites.google.com/site/delphibasics/home/delphibasicssnippets/wipedosstub-removedosheaderfrompe

Comment: Is RAM size an issue at all? Or only ROM size?

Answer (score -3):

Try to improve your program with "programming" tricks. Bill Gates was actually a really good programmer in his younger years, read some programming examples from him.

Use smaller data types, for example, use char instead of int (where it's possible), or use int16 instead of int32.

Remove redundant data, for example:

```
#define WIDTH 100
#define HEIGHT 100
```

Use only:

```
#define DIMENSION 100
```

Don't use `struct`.

Don't use buffer, if possible.

Don't use `int argc, char *argv[]`.

Use keyboard as only input device.

Don't use those kind of arrays:

```
int neighbors[8][2] = {{0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1},
                      {0,-1},        {-1,0},
                      {-1,-1},{-1,1},{1,-1}};
```

use instead a boolean table: int32 neighbors = 0b 0001 0100 0101 0011 1100 1111 1101 0111 (This boolean tables only needs 32bit memory, where your array needs 8 x 2 x 32bit = 512bit, a half Kbit ;-))

Compile your program with best minimizing settings which work, aka the 6KB program version. Open your compiled program with a disassembler and hexeditor and remove all unneeded stuff like plaintext and other overhead and etc.. Be warned, this is a lot of work.

Comment: Replacing 2 preprocessor defines with one does absolutely nothing to reduce executable size. Also replacing data types with smaller ones can actually increase the executable size depending on which architecture you compile for.

Comment: To user694733: Good argument. To make sure that something like that doesn't happens, make a list of all used variables and constants and their needed memory size and create one huge custom block of a datamap, which inhabitants all your constants and variables. This is probably the most memory efficient way to store such things, but also the most complicated.

EDIT: @Lundin, you are wrong. Look at my example with the neighbour array. Every constant, every defined variable uses program memory to the full extend of it's datatype.

Comment: If you specify an operation on a 32 bit type but the compiler can deduct that 32 bits aren't needed, then it may optimize the code size. For example `uint32_t u32 = 1; uint8_t u8=2; uint8_t x = u32 + u8;` might be optimized to use 8 bit instructions, since there is no implicit promotion etc affecting the result.

Comment: As for the "neighbors" array, it's a contrived example and not something you'll commonly encounter. And to read/write to your specialized 32 bit type, you need a lot more code so it is far more inefficient in terms of code size. Again, the goal here is to reduce code size, not variable RAM.

Comment: @Lundin An initialized variable or constant takes as much program memory as it takes data memory. An initialized and defined `int neighbors[8][2]` array takes 512 bit space within the stored program code, so reducing data types is essential for reducing program memory.